# Отключить запись ошибок в файл

Tags: php, php7, php8

Как отключить возможность записи ошибок в логи, в файл site.ru.error.log

В одни записи о том, что та или иная переменная не объявлена. К примеру

```
[Sun Aug 07 22:16:52.602550 2022] [php:warn] [pid 1334] [client 167.*.*.159:37266] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "jmenumin"
[Sun Aug 07 22:16:52.612230 2022] [php:warn] [pid 1334] [client 167.*.*.159:37266] PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $list in
```

Сегодня стало неожиданностью, не запускался сайт, 502 ошибка, дело в том, что размер логов был 90гб. Собираюсь отключить запись логов, не вижу необходимости в них. Так как записи в основном о необъявленных переменных.

Comment: Правильно, зачем чинить ошибки, нет сообщений - нет ошибок

Comment: Лучше объявите переменные...

Comment: А для логов настройте logrotate

Comment: Рассматривали функцию [`error_reporting()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)?

Comment: Если уж так лень писать корректный код, отключите логирование notice и warning например) но лучше писать валидный код...

Comment: А потом когда реально чето произойдет - будешь на кофейной гуще гадать, специалист.

Comment: `logrotate` настраивай как и написали выше